# How to get NodeJS to proxy Client Certificates like Jetty Proxy

Tags: java, node.js, http-proxy, node-http-proxy

I am writing a NodeJS proxy that will replace a [Java Jetty Proxy](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/proxy/ProxyServlet.Transparent.html). I am using [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy). The only piece remaining is to have the original client certificate passed along to the proxied server.

From my understanding, the Java Servlet specification requires that a Servlet container pull the [Client Certificate from an HTTPS request and store that as an attribute on the HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29).

I am not sure how the Servlet Container handles the Attributes when proxying the request to a new server. I presume that it is attaching them somehow either as headers or by some other means.

Does anyone know how those attributes (specifically the `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate`) are passed on a proxied HTTPS request? And two, how do I achieve the same functionality using NodeJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event that is helps someone else out... The issue turned out to be the node module I was using (node-http-proxy) wasn't reusing the HTTP server connection certificates. That is, when attempting to create a connection with the proxy server, it was using a default (generated) certificate.

To properly connect with the proxy server, I had to pass the ca, pfx, and passphrase to the proxy connector.

```
const ca = ...
const pfx = ...
const passphrase = ...

// proxy connection
server.web(req, res, { ca: ca, pfx: pfx, passphrase: passphrase }, function(err) {});
```

After doing so, the Proxy server was able to pull and validate the certificate.